# Using Array.reduce on Node Streams with Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, stream

I am fairly new to typescript and am not familiar with the more advanced type declarations.

I am attempting to use reduce to chain together a series of node.js stream transforms onto an incoming node.js stream.

The incoming stream is an object that extends `stream.Readable`. The stream transform objects all extend `stream.Transform`.

I have an array of these transform objects and I essentially want the final result to be:

`let outStream = inStream.pipe(transform1).pipe(transform2).pipe(transform3)`

This works fine when manually piping each element, however I am unable to determine the correct typescript declaration to achieve this using `Array.prototype.reduce`.

My code looks as follows:

```
class MyReadable extends stream.Readable { ... }
class MyTransform extends stream.Transform { ... }

let inStream = new MyReadable( /* ... */ )

let transforms = [
  new MyTransform( /* ... */ ),
  new MyTransform( /* ... */ ),
  new MyTransform( /* ... */ )
];

let outStream = transforms.reduce(
  (stream: MyReadable, transform: MyTransform): MyReadable => (
    stream.pipe(transform);
  ),
  inStream
);
```

This throws a typescript error because `.pipe(transform)` returns a `MyTransform` type which is not compatible with `MyReadable` type which extends `stream.Readable`.

I have tried doing:

```
let stream = transforms.reduce(
  (stream: ReadableStream, transform: MyTransform): ReadableStream => (
    stream.pipe(transform);
  ),
  inStream
);
```

because `Readable` implements `NodeJS.ReadableStream` and `stream.Transform` implements `ReadWriteStream` which extends `NodeJS.ReadableStream` but type script says that `ReadableStream` does not have a `pipe` method (even though it is declared in the typescript declaration for `ReadableStream`.

Given that both `Transform` and `Readable` implement pipe is there a way in typescript to coerce these together?

Answer (score 0):

I realized after posting that there is a much simpler way to achieve my goal.

I would still be interested in whether there is an answer to this specific question about how to combine these two Typescript types given that functionally the original solution would work.

My solution:

```
class MyReadable extends stream.Readable { ... }
class MyTransform extends stream.Transform { ... }

let inStream = new MyReadable( /* ... */ )

let transforms = [
  new MyTransform( /* ... */ ),
  new MyTransform( /* ... */ ),
  new MyTransform( /* ... */ )
];

let outStream = inStream.pipe(transforms.reduce(
  (stream: MyTransform, transform: MyTransform): MyTransform => (
    stream.pipe(transform);
  ),
  transforms[0]
));
```

Comment: Just as a quick suggestion, you don't have to specify all the types, you can rely on TS's inference. Also reduce already takes the first element of the array without an initial value: `inStream.pipe(transforms.reduce((acc, transform) => acc.pipe(transform)));`

Comment: Thanks @Gustorn, I had forgotten that reduce sets the accumulator by default.